# Re-use scoped ILogger instance from Azure Function

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm not sure what is the best way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish so let me give you an example.

I am using Azure Functions, which are stateless, with the following signature.

```
public static Task Run(Message message, ILogger logger)
{
    var controller = Main.Container.GetInstance<ConsumerController>();

    // How can I attach the passed in logger instance so the rest of
    // the services for the current flow re-use this instance?

    return controller.Execute(message);
}
```

As you can see, the azure function framework passes me an instance of the ILogger already configured and initialized for **this** function call **only**.

I read through the documentation and I think I need a new scope here but I'm not sure. I only want this ILogger instance to be used during the **async** execution of this **one** method call. Each function call will use their own.

And just to be clear, the **controller** is only **one** of possibly **many** services (services, repositories, request handlers) involved in the execution of the task.

Any help would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Create a Proxy (e.g. `ProxyLogger`) implementation that implements `ILogger`, contains a `ILogger Logger` property, and forwards any call to that property.
- Register that Proxy both as `ILogger` and `ProxyLogger` as `Lifestyle.Scoped`.
- Resolve `ProxyLogger` within your function.
- Set `ProxyLogger.Logger` using the function's supplied `ILogger`.
- Resolve the root object and use it.

Create a Proxy:

```
public class ProxyLogger : ILogger
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel l, EventId id, TState s, Exception ex,
       Func<TState,Exception,String> f) =>
       this.Logger.Log<TState>(l, id, s, ex, f);
    // Implement other functions
}
```

Register that Proxy:

```
container.Register<ProxyLogger>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<ILogger, ProxyLogger>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Resolve `ProxyLogger` within your function, set `ProxyLogger.Logger` using the function's supplied `ILogger`, and resolve the root object and use it.

```
public static Task Run(Message message, ILogger logger)
{
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(Main.Container)
    {
        Main.Container.GetInstance<ProxyLogger>().Logger = logger;

        var controller = Main.Container.GetInstance<ConsumerController>();

        return controller.Execute(message);
    }
}
```

I do think, however, that this model leads to a very large amount of infrastructural code. Preferably you wish to keep this infrastructure to the absolute minimum. Instead, you could try keeping your Azure Functions small Humble Objects, as described [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/536). That might not completely solve your initial problem, but you might not need to have a method specific logger anyway. But if, on the other hand, you need that, you might be able to mix that Humble Object approach with the use of C#'s [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information) attribute and the `ProxyLogger` approach. You don't really need the Azure injected `ILogger` to do that for you.

Comment: ok that sounds like a plan. can you show me pseudo code from the 3rd bullet point down? i just wanna make sure that I understand completely.

Comment: i know you didn't mention it but should i be using the async scoped lifestyle? sorry, it's been a long time since i have used simple injector.

Comment: this is great steven thank you! funny enough, i actually was treating my azure function as humble object that's why i have a corresponding controller object. all i really wanted was an app insights logger which comes out of the box hard-wired using azure functions v2. i see what your saying though, just configure the logger in the composition root.